# Problema con ConnectionString

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

Tengo un problema con el connection string:

Poniendolo directamente en el SqlConnection me funciona:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("server=DESKTOP-Q5REQCB\\MSSQLSERVER01 ; database=Synergy ; user id = Synergy; password = SynergyPass");
```

Intentando acceder a él desde el web.config no conecta:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

web.config:

```
 <connectionStrings >
    <add
      name="myConnectionString"
      connectionString="server=DESKTOP-Q5REQCB\\MSSQLSERVER01 ; database=Synergy ; user id = Synergy; password = SynergyPass "
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

Y pruebo a imprimir por consola

```
Debug.WriteLine(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString)
```

E imprime la cadena perfectamente.

¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Te da algún error al crear la `SqlConnection`? Por otro lado, ten cuidado con los espacios en blanco en la connectionString por si acaso. Eliminales todos

Comment: @Pikoh me salta la excepción: System.InvalidOperationException: Error de instancia. Los elimino todos? incluso el de "user id" a "userid"?

Comment: @Pikoh Nada, probado quitando los espacios y pasa lo mismo. Dejando el espacio de "user id", si no, me decía argumento inválido, logicamente jaja

Comment: Intenta una cosa: cambia el doble backslash por uno solo y prueba a ver: `server=DESKTOP-Q5REQCB\MSSQLSERVER01`

Comment: @Pikoh Venga ya... era esa tontería jaja Gracias!

Comment: Suele pasar. Voy a añadir respuesta por si le pasa a algun otro :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando se añade una `ConnectionString` en el fichero de configuración, no es necesario escapar el `backSlash` poniéndolo doble `\\`,hay que poner solo uno `\`. En este caso, debe quedar así:

```
<connectionStrings >
    <add
       name="myConnectionString"
       connectionString="server=DESKTOP-Q5REQCB\MSSQLSERVER01 ; database=Synergy ; user id = Synergy; password = SynergyPass "
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```